# Zend Framework very bad performance on WAMP

Tags: windows, performance, zend-framework, wamp

I am developing a project on windows with wamp installed using zend framework.
Unfortunately it has very slow performance, although I did the things mentioned in the manual:

- remove require once
- added apc

I recently installed Scienta ZF Debug Bar v1.3, and here is an example of results i get:

> Queries: 48 in 53.01 ms
>   Memory: 9188 KB
>   Controller time: 8335.74 ms

I cant figure out why it works so slow.
Any help is greatly apreciated.

EDIT:

Got xdebug profiler to work eventually, and it is very strange since I see the page load and it is a lot ... 6-7 seconds like the bar is telling me ... but in wincachegrid i see a total run time of 641ms ... i am :|

Comment: Have you ever solved this problem?

Comment: cached some mysql queryies and models and got some better performence, but still slow on wamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few more suggestions:

- Check your error logs, as most of the runtime is in your controller, it might be dumping tons of errors.
- Consider using the [xcache](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/) or [eaccelerator](http://eaccelerator.net/) opcode caches instead of APC (obsolete I believe).
- Put some timing code in the controller to see if you can identify the the slowest sections of code.

Comment: i have installed eaccelerator ... same situation.

Comment: the problem is that online it performes OK ... but localy on windows its all really slow.

Comment: Again, make sure you check the server logs on your local machine. It really sounds like you have some difference in configuration that's making the app write out tons of errors or just generally misbehave.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried profiling the application? Zend Studio and [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) both give the ability to profile your application and see what exactly is taking so long.

Comment: unfortunately the i cant open the profiles with wincache grid i get a parse error: fl is not valid
cachegrid.out line number 99305